# Pandas - Replacing Values by Looking Up in an Another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem to solve in my pandas dataframe with Python3. I have two dataframes - the first one is as;

```
    ID Name  Linked Model 1  Linked Model 2  Linked Model 3
0  100    A          1111.0          1112.0             NaN
1  101    B          1112.0          1113.0          1115.0
2  102    C             NaN             NaN             NaN
3  103    D          1114.0             NaN             NaN
4  104    E          1114.0          1111.0          1112.0
```

the second one is;

```
   Model ID Name
0      1111    A
1      1112  A,B
2      1113    C
3      1114    D
4      1115    Q
5      1116    Z
6      1117    E
7      1118    W
```

So the code should look up the value in - for instance in **Linked Model 1** column and find the corresponding value in **Name** column in the second dataframe so that the ID can be replaced with name just like as shown in the result;

[image]

So as you can see in the result output, None stays as None (could be replaced numpy N/As) and the names from the second dataframe are now replaced with their corresponding **Model ID**s in the first dataframe.

I am looking forward to hearing your solutions!

Thanks

Comment: This is `replace` problem .

Comment: However, the Question is good but again the basic problem of attaching picture is there which really not helps to reproduce the problem  and place a answer, better would be placing code syntax would help in real. Creating dataframe and devices solution is time consuming.

Comment: @coldspeed,  thnx,  this  indeed helps a lot because showcasing pics hels no way!

Comment: Yes right. Sorry guys for picture-source data, I appreciate your feedback! Lesson learned

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - replace values in dataframe based on another dataframe match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52872582/python-replace-values-in-dataframe-based-on-another-dataframe-match)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Initialise a replacement dictionary and use [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to map those IDs to Names.

```
m = df2.set_index('Model ID')['Name'].to_dict()
v = df.filter(like='Linked Model')
df[v.columns] = v.replace(m)
```

```
df
    ID Name Linked Model 1 Linked Model 2 Linked Model 3
0  100    A              A            A,B            NaN
1  101    B            A,B              C              Q
2  102    C            NaN            NaN            NaN
3  103    D              D            NaN            NaN
4  104    E              D              A            A,B
```

Comment: I wonder whether there is a faster parallelized way similar to stata since on my 1mln rows x 15 cols data pandas takes more than one hour (I stopped it) while with a simple stata foreach loop takes about 3-4 minutes `foreach var of varlist var1-var15{ vlookup \`var', gen(q\`var') key(id) value(name)}`

Answer (score 2):

First attempt to answer a python question, so while this is certainly longer than coldspeed's answer, it makes more sense to me using the `melt`, `merge`, and `pivot` funcitons.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# make an object from the first dataset

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
  {"ID" : [100, 101, 102, 103, 104],
  "Name" : ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
  "Linked Model 1" : [1111, 1112, np.nan, 1114, 1114],
  "Linked Model 2" : [1112, 1113, np.nan, np.nan, 1111],
  "Linked Model 3" : [np.nan, 1115, np.nan, np.nan, 1112]})

# make an object for the second data set

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(
  {"Model ID" : [1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1115, 1116, 1117, 1118],
  "Name" : ["A", "A,B", "C", "D", "Q", "Z", "E", "W"]})

# tidy the data
df_1 = pd.melt(df_1, ["ID", "Name"]) 

# left join the second data set
df_1 = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='left', left_on='value', right_on='Model ID').reset_index()

#pivot the data back out to achieve the desired format
df_1 = df_1.pivot_table(index='ID', 
                        columns='variable', 
                        values='Name_y', 
                        aggfunc='first', 
                        dropna=False))

variable Linked Model 1 Linked Model 2 Linked Model 3
ID                                                   
100                   A            A,B            NaN
101                 A,B              C              Q
102                 NaN            NaN            NaN
103                   D            NaN            NaN
104                   D              A            A,B
```