# Replace comma-separated values in a dataframe with values from another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

this is my first question on StackOverflow, so please pardon if I am not clear enough. I usually find my answers here but this time I had no luck. Maybe I am being dense, but here we go.

I have two pandas dataframes formatted as follows

**df1**

```
+------------+-------------+
| References | Description |
+------------+-------------+
| 1,2        | Descr 1     |
| 3          | Descr 2     |
| 2,3,5      | Descr 3     |
+------------+-------------+
```

**df2**

```
+--------+--------------+
| Ref_ID |   ShortRef   |
+--------+--------------+
|      1 | Smith (2006) |
|      2 | Mike (2009)  |
|      3 | John (2014)  |
|      4 | Cole (2007)  |
|      5 | Jill (2019)  |
|      6 | Tom (2007)   |
+--------+--------------+
```

Basically, *Ref_ID* in **df2** contains IDs that form the string contained in the field *References* in **df1**

What I would like to do is to replace values in the *References* field in **df1** so it looks like this:

```
+-------------------------------------+-------------+
|             References              | Description |
+-------------------------------------+-------------+
| Smith (2006); Mike (2009)           | Descr 1     |
| John (2014)                         | Descr 2     |
| Mike (2009);John (2014);Jill (2019) | Descr 3     |
+-------------------------------------+-------------+
```

So far, I had to deal with columns and IDs with a 1-1 relationship, and this works perfectly
[Pandas - Replacing Values by Looking Up in an Another Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53818434/pandas-replacing-values-by-looking-up-in-an-another-dataframe)

But I cannot get my mind around this slightly different problem. The only solution I could think of is to re-iterate a for and if cycles that compare every string of **df1** to **df2** and make the substitution.

This would be, I am afraid, very slow as I have ca. 2000 unique *Ref_ID*s and I have to repeat this operation in several columns similar to the *References* one.

Anyone is willing to point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: EDIT: thanks for the hints, I am trying them out. One thing I am now struggling with is that some cells within "References" are empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Reference':['1,2','3','1,3,5'], 'Description':['Descr 1', 'Descr 2', 'Descr 3']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Ref_ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'ShortRef':['Smith (2006)',
                                                       'Mike (2009)',
                                                       'John (2014)',
                                                       'Cole (2007)',
                                                       'Jill (2019)',
                                                       'Tom (2007)']})

df1['Reference2'] = (df1['Reference'].str.split(',')
                                     .explode()
                                     .map(df2.assign(Ref_ID=df2.Ref_ID.astype(str))
                                             .set_index('Ref_ID')['ShortRef'])
                                     .groupby(level=0).agg(list))
```

Output:

```
  Reference Description                                Reference2
0       1,2     Descr 1               [Smith (2006), Mike (2009)]
1         3     Descr 2                             [John (2014)]
2     1,3,5     Descr 3  [Smith (2006), John (2014), Jill (2019)]
```

@Datanovice thanks for the update.

```
df1['Reference2'] = (df1['Reference'].str.split(',')
                                     .explode()
                                     .map(df2.assign(Ref_ID=df2.Ref_ID.astype(str))
                                             .set_index('Ref_ID')['ShortRef'])
                                     .groupby(level=0).agg(';'.join))
```

Output:

```
  Reference Description                            Reference2
0       1,2     Descr 1              Smith (2006);Mike (2009)
1         3     Descr 2                           John (2014)
2     1,3,5     Descr 3  Smith (2006);John (2014);Jill (2019)
```

Comment: One gotcha... is checking the dtypes between df1 Reference and df2 Reference.

Comment: doesnt appear OP wants the `[...]` around references, is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: `df['Reference2'] = df["References"].str.split(",").explode().astype(int).map(
    df2.set_index("Ref_ID")["ShortRef"]
).groupby(level=0).agg(';'.join)` i think to sort out the dtypes ;)

Comment: This solution works perfectly! thank you very muck, I will add a pingback to this page into my code.

Comment: After implementing the solution, I noticed that in some cases values are misplaced. E.g. in the case above, instead of finding only "John (2014)" related to Reference ID 3, I also find "Smith (2006)". But this happens only at specific records, e.g. other rows with Reference ID = 3 are substituted ok.
Weird behavior...

Comment: Found the problem. My dataframe was deriving from a merge, therefore the index was not sequntial. I used df = df.reset_index() before running the code.

Comment: @AlessioRovere Great.  I am glad you found the problem.

Comment: what wil be the alternative for pandas version 0.24.0? explode is not a property of this version

Comment: @phonix Try this: `df1.set_index('Description').join(df1.set_index('Description')['Reference'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
    .map(df2.assign(Ref_ID=df2.Ref_ID.astype(str))
    .set_index('Ref_ID')['ShortRef'])
    .groupby(level=0).agg(';'.join).rename('Ref2')).reset_index()`

Answer (score 3):

you can use some list comprehension and dict lookups and I dont think this will be too slow

First, making a fast-to-access mapping for id to short_ref

```
mapping_dict = df2.set_index('Ref_ID')['ShortRef'].to_dict()
```

Then, lets split references by commas

```
df1_values = [v.split(',') for v in df1['References']]
```

Finally, we can iterate over and do dictionary lookups, before concatenating back to strings

```
df1['References'] = pd.Series([';'.join([mapping_dict[v] for v in values]) for values in df1_values])
```

Is this usable or is it too slow?

Comment: this is really good, but you can make use of `explode` and `str.split` to make for fewer lines of code.

Comment: if speed is a concern this may be faster though

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is using `str.get_dummies` and `dot`

```
df3 = (df1.set_index('Description').Reference.str.get_dummies(',')
          .reindex(columns=df2.Ref_ID.astype(str).values, fill_value=0))
df_final = (df3.dot(df2.ShortRef.values+';').str.strip(';').rename('References')
               .reset_index())

Out[462]:
  Description                           References
0     Descr 1             Smith (2006);Mike (2009)
1     Descr 2                          John (2014)
2     Descr 3  Mike (2009);John (2014);Jill (2019)
```

Comment: This one works as well, and the error I mention above does not occur.